# Python numpy: Data file with multiple datasets

Tags: python, numpy, plot

Suppose you have a data file which includes several data sets separated by the string "--" in the following format:

```
--
<x0_val> <y0_val>
<x1_val> <y1_val>
<x2_val> <y2_val>
--
<x0_val> <y0_val>
<x1_val> <y1_val>
<x2_val> <y2_val>
...
```

How can you read the whole file into an array of arrays so that you can plot all data sets afterwards to the same picture with a `for` loop looping over the outer array ?

```
genfromtxt('data.dat', delimiter=("--"))
```

gives lots of

```
Line #1550 (got 1 columns instead of 2)
```

Comment: See:
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy

Comment: See [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223965/how-to-parse-block-data-from-a-text-file-into-an-2d-array-in-python/12227618#12227618)

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? You can use split via two delimiters (first `--`, then `' '`.

Answer (score 1):

I will update ...

I would first split the file into multiple files, which can reside in memory as objects or on the filesystems as new files.

You can locate the string `--` with the module `re`.

Then you can use the link I posted above.

Comment: There are 130 data sets. Really split into multiple files?

Comment: @Frank, why not? If it is only in the memory, no harm is done. If it is persistent, it will be easier to work later.

Answer (score 1):

If you're 100% certain that you have no negative values in your file, you can try a quick:

```
np.genfromtxt(your_file, comments="-")
```

The `comments="-"` will force `genfromtxt` to ignore all the characters after `-`, which of course will give weird results if you have negative variables. Moreover, the result will be just a lump of your dataset in a single array

Otherwise, the safest route is to iterate on your file and store the lines that do not match `--` in one list per block, something along the lines:

```
blocks = []
current = []
for line in your_file:
    if line.startswith("-"):
        blocks.append(np.array(current))
        current = []
    else:
        current += line.split()
```

You may have to get rid of the first block if empty.

You could also check a [`mmap` based solution already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223965/how-to-parse-block-data-from-a-text-file-into-an-2d-array-in-python/12227618#12227618).

Comment: No, with `commments` it just combines all data sets. It doesn't create an array of arrays.

Comment: Yes, it will jst make ahuge array of all your dataset concatenated. The `comments="-"` forces `np.genfromtxt` to skip the lines that have a `-` in them. Once again, bad idea if you have negative values. If you want an array of array, construct individual lists per block, then transform each list into an array.